# how to get the provider access token in next-auth

Tags: reactjs, next.js, google-signin, next-auth

Hi I am new to nextjs and for authentication I am using next-auth. The users can log in using Google and when they are logged in and authenticated I want to get the access_token given by provider in this case Google.
Although I can get that inside signIn callback function but is there a way to globally access that?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

you can create the callbacks key in the nextAuth config as below to access your userId and access_token, as well.

```js
callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      session.user.id = token.id;
      session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
      return session;
    },
    async jwt({ token, user, account, profile, isNewUser }) {
      if (user) {
        token.id = user.id;
      }
      if (account) {
        token.accessToken = account.access_token;
      }
      return token;
    },
  },
```

Comment: it seems like the accessToken is now removed from the Session type: https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/upgrade-v4#schema-changes . Is there another way to do it with the latest version?

Comment: account in not null only when you sign in and you have no way of refreshing access_token

Comment: i had to define the session callback as follow and I was able to access token it in the session:

callbacks: {
        async session({ session, token, user }) {           
            return {
                ...session,
                token: token
            };
        }
    }

Answer (score 14):

for **next-auth v4** (and higher): 
I had a problem accessing the access token inside the jwt callback, apparently, they have changed the schema and now accessToken is only stored in the Account table. 
If you are storing user data in a database using an adapter, you could query the Account table inside the session function. In my case I was using the Prisma adapter and this worked fine for me:

`async session({ session, token, user }) {
      const getToken = await prisma.account.findFirst({
        where: {
          userId: user.id,
        },
      });

      let accessToken: string | null = null;
      if (getToken) {
        accessToken = getToken.access_token!;
      }

      session.user.token = accessToken;
      return session;
    },`



**If you are using typescript and you want to return the token to the client**, there is one more step you should do because it would complain otherwise, 
Create a **/types** directory inside your source folder and add a **next-auth-d.ts** file inside of it. 
You will extend the session interface here

`` import NextAuth, { DefaultSession } from "next-auth";

declare module "next-auth" {
  /**
   * Returned by `useSession`, `getSession` and received as a prop on the `SessionProvider` React Context
   */
  interface Session {
    user: {
      /** Oauth access token */
      token?: accessToken;
    } & DefaultSession["user"];
  }
} ``

You can now access the session from clientside:

`import React from "react";
import { useSession, signIn, signOut } from "next-auth/react";

type Props = {};

function ExampleComponent({}: Props) {
  const { data: session } = useSession();

  if (session) {
    return (
      <>
        Access token {session.user.token} <br />
        <button onClick={() => signOut()}>Sign out</button>
      </>
    );
  }
  return (
    <>
      Not signed in <br />
      <button onClick={() => signIn("discord")}>Sign in with Discord</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default ExampleComponent;`

Comment: Do I need to register that next-auth.d.ts file somewhere? I still cannot augment my session object

Comment: No, it should automatically pick the type up, refer to:
https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/typescript#main-module

Comment: Be sure the 'NEXTAUTH_SECRET' is set to a strong password! If you don't the access token can be obtained by an evil party, by brute force, this password should not be easily obtained! rotating the `NEXTAUTH_SECRET` is probably a good idea

Comment: I want to share the user session data to Node.js(apollo-graphql) and I tried many ways to solve that problem but I have still errors.   you can see my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77593030/i-cant-read-session-when-i-pass-from-next-auth-to-nodejs

Answer (score 9):

In Next Auth v4, the accessToken is now in the account object so you can get it with the jwt callback assign it to the token object and then assign it to session object using a callback as well.

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import GithubProvider from "next-auth/providers/github"


export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    GithubProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
  
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({token, account}) {
      if (account) {
        token = Object.assign({}, token, { access_token: account.access_token });
      }
      return token
    },
    async session({session, token}) {
    if(session) {
      session = Object.assign({}, session, {access_token: token.access_token})
      console.log(session);
      }
    return session
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, just need the `next-auth-d.ts` snippet included in @Berke's answer if you're working in TypeScript.

Answer (score 4):

Please refer to this [post](https://blog.srij.dev/nextauth-google-access-token) which i think will help.

Please be aware of next-auth version, in V4 you can access the access token by: account.access_token, before V4 it will be account.accessToken.

Also this [link](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks) will help wih callbacks in next0auth V4.

Answer (score 2):

for Credentials login

use callbacks like this

```
callbacks: {
    jwt: async ({ token, user }) => {
        user && (token.user = user)
        return token
    },
    session: async ({ session, token }) => {
        session.user = token.user
        return session
    }
}
```

then in page import

```
import { getSession ,useSession, signIn, signOut } from "next-auth/react";
```

and use this for get token

```
const { data: token, status } = useSession()
console.log(token)
```

for get sessin use this

```
const { data: session, status } = useSession()
console.log(session)
```

Comment: That's not true. In your answer: `const { data: token, status }` and `const { data: session, status }` won't give you two different results, but the same. This means token & session will be the same object. The colon in object destructuring just renames the given variable.

Answer (score -1):

You can access this using the `getSession` method, which can be used server-side (i.e. in next.js methods like `getServerSideProps` and client side (i.e. in your normal react components).

See: https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#getsession

Answer (score -1):

```
callbacks: {
  async jwt({ token, user, account, profile, isNewUser }) {
    if (account) {
      console.log(account.id_token)
    }
  },
},
```