# How to get hold of access_token or id_token when using SvelteKitAuth with Cognito?

Tags: jwt, amazon-cognito, sveltekit, next-auth

I am developing a SvelteKit app and am using Cognito as my authentication provider. For one of the AWS APIs I'm calling ([IsAuthorizedWithToken](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/verifiedpermissions/latest/apireference/API_IsAuthorizedWithToken.html)), I need to provide the logged-in user's access/identity token. Essentially, I want to get hold of the tokens somehow in one of my `+page.server.ts` file.

```ts
// somefolder/+page.server.ts

export async function load({ locals }) {
    const session = await locals.getSession();
    const { id_token, access_token } = session

    // Make use of id_token, access_token
}
```

Inspired by [how to get the provider access token in next-auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69068495/how-to-get-the-provider-access-token-in-next-auth), I used the `jwt` callback to get the tokens when the user logs in. I verfied the tokens were there in `session` using console log.

However, as soon as I refresh the page the tokens become `undefined` even though the user is still logged in and I have access to other properties in session like `user.email`. By this I inferred that the token are only made available when the user logs in, not for subsequent requests.

```ts
// hooks.server.ts

import { SvelteKitAuth } from '@auth/sveltekit';
import Cognito from '@auth/core/providers/cognito';
import { AUTH_SECRET, COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID, COGNITO_CLIENT_SECRET } from '$env/static/private';
import { PUBLIC_COGNITO_CLIENT_ID } from '$env/static/public';
import type { Handle } from '@sveltejs/kit';

// https://authjs.dev/reference/sveltekit
export const handle = SvelteKitAuth({
    secret: AUTH_SECRET,
    providers: [
        // https://authjs.dev/reference/core/providers_cognito
        Cognito({
            clientId: PUBLIC_COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: COGNITO_CLIENT_SECRET,
            issuer: `https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/${COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID}`
        })
    ],
    callbacks: {
        async session({ session, token }) {
            session.user && (session.user.sub = token.sub);
            session.access_token = token.accessToken as string;
            session.id_token = token.id_token as string;
            console.log(session);
            return session;
        },
        async jwt({ token, account }) {
            if (account) {
                token.access_token = account.access_token;
                token.id_token = account.id_token;
            }
            return token;
        }
    }
}) satisfies Handle;
```

Q1: Why are the tokens only available when the users logs in, not for subsequent requests? What's SvelteKitAuth doing with the tokens?

Q2: What's the `correct` way of getting hold of the tokens in my `+page.server.ts`?

Whilst it'd be nice to get an answer to fix my current problem, I'm interested in understanding why things are this way.

GitHub issue also created: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/8156

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

You have a typo in your session callback :

```js
session.access_token = token.accessToken as string;
```

should be :

```js
session.access_token = token.access_token as string;
```

as `token` is created in jwt callback with the property `token.access_token` and not `token.accessToken`. That's why `session.access_token` was `undefined`.

Then the Cognito tokens should be available in subsequent requests on your page.

Comment: I’m after the Cognito tokens, not the Auth.js token.

Comment: The Cognito token is stored in Auth.js token. It should be accessible on server in session.access_token.

Comment: No, it's definitely not in `session` by default. I had to get it from `account` as I said in my question.

Comment: Yes sure, but I was talking about the implementation in your code.
Btw I found your mistake so I updated my original answer.

Comment: Ah thanks for spotting that.